# Material UI Autocomplete clearOnBlur clears when false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

In a recent project, I am using Material UI's Autocomplete.
There I do not want the input field to be cleared, so I use the `clearOnBlur` property set to `false`.

Even then, the Autocompleter clears the input field after focus is lost.

Would appreciate the help!

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-moon-2bk87?file=/src/ComboBox.js

Comment: The code is attached is working successfully. Whats' the problem?

Comment: The input is NOT supposed to be cleared.

Comment: @Julien You may be right! I tried some of their examples in their own CodeSandbox and there the `clearOnBlur` feature also does not work. 
Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I made this sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h8sol, from the playground demo,https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground. Input is not cleared on blur.

Sorry, deleted my comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox! I just found out it has been fixed recently in this PR https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/28190.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in `material-ui 5.0.0-beta` which you're using it has problem. In `4.12.3` it's working properly. Please check out this `codesandbox`:

```
const ComboBox = function () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const Combo = useRef();

  const onBlur = (e) => {
    Combo.current.inputValue = value;
  };

  const filterOptions = (options, state) => {
    return options;
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      ref={Combo}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      onSelect={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      clearOnBlur={false}
      inputValue={value}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried to set the input value manually but because of the `material-ui` version, It doesn't work.

[image: Edit laughing-mountain-k1ie1]

Comment: Thanks! This is absolutely correct. In the newest version of Material UI, the option does not work. Luckily though, there is already a PR for this particular problem and will hopefully be out soon. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/28190

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest version of the material UI, It's always good to use the latest version.

Try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/clear-on-blur-autocomplete-zrhj3) sandbox with the latest version of MUI.

This is adapted from the documentation demo sandbox from [here](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground).